# Raspberry Pi 3, Ubuntu Core 18, Mounting USB disk fails

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, raspberry-pi, systemd

I have Ubuntu Core running on a Raspberry 3 and I am trying to mount external USB disk and have followed the instructions on: [Mount instructions](https://flexion.org/posts/2016-12-raspberry-pi-3-powered-nextcloud-box-on-ubuntu-core/)

When running the command

```
igor-lopez@localhost:~$ systemctl start home-igor-lopez-backup-vol1.mount
```

I get the failure:

> Failed to start home-igor-lopez-backup-vol1.mount: Unit home-igor-lopez-backup-vol1.mount is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.

My mount file(/writable/system-data/etc/systemd/system/home-igor-lopez-backup-vol1.mount) looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount for Backup Vol1

[Mount]
What=/dev/disk/by-uuid/eb48ffde-6fcd-48e4-a31b-316628728f4c
Where=/home/igor-lopez/backup/vol1
Type=ext4

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and the mount point does exist:

```
igor-lopez@localhost:~/backup/vol1$ pwd
/home/igor-lopez/backup/vol1
```

and so does the disk:

> /dev/disk/by-uuid/eb48ffde-6fcd-48e4-a31b-316628728f4c -> ../../sda1

Since the user was created during install and connected to my launchpad account I have a dash in the user name. The mount file should have a name matching the mount point but slash replased with dash but I do not want to change the user name if I can avoid it.
Running the same command with sudo gave additional info:

> Jan 05 13:24:28 localhost.localdomain systemd[1](https://flexion.org/posts/2016-12-raspberry-pi-3-powered-nextcloud-box-on-ubuntu-core/): home-igor-lopez-backup-vol1.mount: Where= setting doesn't match unit name. Refusing.

So it looks like the mount file entry:

```
Where=/home/igor-lopez/backup/vol1
```

is the culprit and I have no idea on how to solve it.

Tried changing the Where location according reply by grawity to:

```
Where=/home/igor\x2dlopez/backup/vol1
```

but that did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since unit file names cannot contain slashes, those are replaced with dashes. But to prevent ambiguity, dashes that were *originally* there must be replaced with something else; systemd uses C-style `\x##` hexadecimal escapes for this. So `igor-lopez` must be written as `igor\x2dlopez`.

Use `systemd-escape` to find the correct name:

```
$ systemd-escape --path /home/igor-lopez/backup/vol1
home-igor\x2dlopez-backup-vol1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I updated the Where location to:   Where=/home/igor\x2dlopez/backup/vol1 but still got the same error.

Comment: You were supposed to update the _unit file name_, not the Where= setting.

Comment: I tried that as well but did not succeed in naming the unit file with \x2d first but then escaping the slash first, mv home-igorx-lopez-backup-vol1.mount home-igor\\x2dlopez-backup-vol1.mount  did the trick and now the start command worked. Thanks for the help.